# Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import selenium.common.exceptions

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))
chrome_options.binary_location ="/opt/google/chrome/chrome"
display.start()
browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
browser.close()
display.stop()
```

Hello
I ran this code with ssh and it had no errors and it ran correctly but when I ran it on the server I got the following error:

```
chromedriver executable may have wrong permissions
```

Now I gave 755 access to chrome driver and chrome paths and now it gives the following error

```
Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

If I ssh with root access I have no error
what should I do?

Comment: Under which user is `chromedriver` saved? I would change the owner of chromedriver to the user you're trying to run with.

Comment: chromedriver is root owner and rwxr-xr-x(755) permissin saved

Comment: try to move it in a different folder with a different owner (i.e. the user you're trying the python script)

Comment: with chown admin:admin path change root owner into admin but error is exists

Comment: Can you kindly paste the full error traceback please?
There must be some other informatin that we might be missing here.

Comment: The problem is that for the Chrome driver, the owner is root and when the file wants to be executed, it is executed with another user, so it cannot, and it requires both user access and permission to execute... Therefore, there is a problem in the server, but there is no problem in ssh. For now, I came to solve this problem and ran the root file with cranjob and it was executed and it is solved for now, but the basic problem is not solved and there must be a much better solution.